# Unchecked call when using generics

Tags: java, generics

I need help working on this generics code.

```
protected AbsPageAdapter getAdapter() {
    return new NewsPageAdapter<>(getSupportFragmentManager(), getConfigs());  // error
}

@Override
protected List<? extends Configuration> getConfigs() {
    return new ConfigHelper(this).getNewsConfigs();
}

public NewsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<T> objects) {
    super(fm, objects);
}
```

Here's the errors:

[image]

[image]

Not sure how to fix this

Comment: I think it's because the return type of that method is not generic.  You're converting from generic to raw type, not safe.  I haven't double checked though.

Comment: NewsPageAdapter is a class or a simple method of your class, that' s a bit ambigous, can you give us a bit more code like the code for AbsPageAdapter please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provide the type of the objects held by getConfigs() to the instance of NewsPageAdapter, for example

```
return new NewsPageAdapter<SomeConfig>(getSupportFragmentManager(), getConfigs());
```

Or it is whatever type defined in class NewsPageAdapter when you instantiate NewsPageAdapter in that line